# Geolocator position does not appear in the console

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocator

Geolocator position does not appear in the console and there is no errors also I have tried to get the longitude and latitude using position.longitude separately but nothing changes , the problem is with this line but I am not able to determine it  :     Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);

and here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  void getLocation() async{
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            getLocation();
          //  _determinePosition();
            //Get the current location
          },
          child: Text('Get Location'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following permission in **AndroidManifest.xml** for accessing location.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Check for service enable or not.

```
bool servicestatus = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();

if(servicestatus){
   print("GPS service is enabled");
}else{
   print("GPS service is disabled.");
}
```

Now try to fetch location details.

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
print(position.longitude); //Output: 80.24599079
print(position.latitude); //Output: 29.6593457
```

Comment: It is enabled but did not get the position